# A ClickOnce application no longer updates itself or ask for update after the message for a new version was skipped

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, .net-7.0

I’m using Visual Studio 2022 Professional Version 17 with NET 7.0. I have the following problem: When I release new version using clickonce. It wont ask again once the the user skip the update. I need the application ask to update the program each run unless they have the newest version.

Following is not available for .net7

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

    try
    {
        UpdateCheckInfo info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();

        if (info.UpdateAvailable)
        {
            bool doUpdate = true;

            if (!info.IsUpdateRequired)
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                if (DialogResult.OK != dr)
                {
                    doUpdate = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("A mandatory update is available. The application will now update and restart.", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            if (doUpdate)
            {
                ad.Update();
                Application.Restart();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
    {
      
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did found this from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet?view=vs-2022 Still. However, still dont know how to ignite the update process

if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_IsNetworkDeployed")?.ToLower() == "true")
{
Version currentVersion = new Version(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion"));
Version updatedVersion = new Version(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_UpdatedVersion"));

```
if (updatedVersion > currentVersion)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Hasan Danaci,

> UpdatedVersion differs from CurrentVersion if a new update has been
> installed but you have not yet called Restart on the Application. If
> the application's deployment manifest is configured to perform
> automatic updates, you can compare these two values to determine
> whether you should restart the application.
>
> If the application has not been updated, UpdatedVersion returns the
> same value as CurrentVersion.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updatedversion?view=netframework-4.8.1

The solution provided below only works if the user has restarted the application since an update has been deployed. It will not work if you are looking to update currently open applications. I have not yet been able to find a solution that works without restarting the application.

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_IsNetworkDeployed")?.ToLower() == "true") { 

Version currentVersion = new 
Version(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion")); 

Version updatedVersion = new 
Version(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_UpdatedVersion"));

if (updatedVersion > currentVersion)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        
    }
}
```